# Array in a dataframe to n dataframe rows

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have 4 column dataframe:

- PERSON ID [int - key]
- PERSON NAME [varchar]
- PERSON POINTS [numpy 1d array of int]
- PERSON DISTANCES [numpy 1d array of int]

As you see the granularity is on the person. I want to create a new dataframe with a new granularity: Person_Points with also 4 columns:

- PERSON_ID [int - key]
- PERSON_NAME [varchar]
- PERSON_POINT [int - key]
- PERSON_DISTANCE [int]
  by creating as many rows as there is element in my 1d numpy arrays.

Exemple of PERSON dataframe:

```
PERSON_ID PERSON_NAME PERSON_POINTS PERSON_DISTANCES
1         A           [1 2 3]       [2 4 6]
2         B           [4 5 6 7]     [2 4 6 8]
3         C           [8]           [6]
4         D           [9 10]        [4 8]
```

Exemple of PERSON_Points dataframe:

```
PERSON_ID PERSON_NAME PERSON_POINT PERSON_DISTANCE
1         A           1             2
1         A           2             4
1         A           3             6
2         B           4             2
2         B           5             4
2         B           6             6
2         B           7             8
3         C           8             6
4         D           9             4
4         D           10            8
```

As my dataframe Person is very large , I am not sure of the best way to do it, and can't find many exemples.
Can someone help here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) as Bruno pointed out

```
# new df with one row per element in PERSON_POINTS and PERSON_DISTANCES
df = df.explode('PERSON_POINTS')
df = df.explode('PERSON_DISTANCES')

print(df)
```

Above is a short example to do it